# Drone CI Stuck on Pending for arm

Tags: kubernetes, drone.io

I'm trying to test ci/cd with gitea and drone but it is stuck in pending.

I was able to verify if my **gitea** is connected to my **drone-server**

[image]

here is my `.drone.yaml`

```
kind: pipeline
type: docker
name: arm64

platform:
  os: linux
  arch: arm64
  
steps:
  - name: test
    image: 'golang:1.10-alpine'
    commands:
      - go test
  - name: build
    image: 'golang:1.10-alpine'
    commands:
      - go build -o ./myapp
  - name: publish
    image: plugins/docker
    settings:
      username: mjayson
      password:
        from_secret: docker_pwd
      repo: mjayson/sample
      tags: latest
  - name: deliver
    image: sinlead/drone-kubectl
    settings:
      kubernetes_server:
        from_secret: k8s_server
      kubernetes_cert:
        from_secret: k8s_cert
      kubernetes_token:
        from_secret: k8s_token
    commands:
      - kubectl apply -f deployment.yml
```

I have set up **gitea** and **drone** in my k8s cluster. Configuration below

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: drone-config
  namespace: dev-ops
data:
  DRONE_GITEA_SERVER: 'http://192.168.1.150:30000'
  DRONE_GITEA_CLIENT_ID: '746a6cd1-cd31-4611-971b-e005bb80e662'
  DRONE_GITEA_CLIENT_SECRET: 'O-NpPnTiFyIGZwqN7aeNDqIWR1sGIEJj8Cehcl0CtVI='
  DRONE_RPC_SECRET: '1be6d1769148d95b5d04a84694cc0447'  
  DRONE_SERVER_HOST: '192.168.1.150:30001'
  DRONE_SERVER_PROTO: 'http'
  DRONE_LOGS_TRACE: 'true'
  DRONE_LOGS_PRETTY: 'true'
  DRONE_LOGS_COLOR: 'true'
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: drone-server-pv
  labels:
    type: local
spec:
  storageClassName: manual
  capacity:
    storage: 5Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  hostPath:
    path: "/infra/drone"
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: drone-server-pvc
spec:
  storageClassName: manual
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 5Gi      
---
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: drone-server-service
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: drone-server
  ports:
  - name: drone-server-http
    port: 80
    targetPort: 80
    nodePort: 30001
  - name: drone-server-ssh
    port: 443
    targetPort: 443
    nodePort: 30003
---    
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: drone-server-deployment
  labels:
    app: drone-server
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: drone-server
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: drone-server
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: drone-server
        image: drone/drone:1.9
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
          name: gitea-http
        - containerPort: 443
          name: gitea-ssh
        envFrom:
        - configMapRef:
            name: drone-config
        volumeMounts:
        - name: pv-data
          mountPath: /data
      volumes:
      - name: pv-data
        persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: drone-server-pvc
```

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: drone-runner-deployment
  labels:
    app: drone-runner
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: drone-runner
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: drone-runner
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: drone-runner
          image: 'drone/drone-runner-kube:latest'
          ports:
            - containerPort: 3000
              name: runner-http
          env:
            - name: DRONE_RPC_HOST
              valueFrom:
                configMapKeyRef:
                  name: drone-config
                  key: DRONE_SERVER_HOST
            - name: DRONE_RPC_PROTO
              valueFrom:
                configMapKeyRef:
                  name: drone-config
                  key: DRONE_SERVER_PROTO
            - name: DRONE_RPC_SECRET
              valueFrom:
                configMapKeyRef:
                  name: drone-config
                  key: DRONE_RPC_SECRET
            - name: DRONE_RUNNER_CAPACITY
              value: '2'
            - name: DRONE_LOGS_TRACE
              valueFrom:
                configMapKeyRef:
                  name: drone-config
                  key: DRONE_LOGS_TRACE
            - name: DRONE_LOGS_PRETTY
              valueFrom:
                configMapKeyRef:
                  name: drone-config
                  key: DRONE_LOGS_PRETTY
            - name: DRONE_LOGS_COLOR
              valueFrom:
                configMapKeyRef:
                  name: drone-config
                  key: DRONE_LOGS_COLOR
```

and here is the **drone server logs**

```
}
{
  "arch": "",
  "kernel": "",
  "kind": "pipeline",
  "level": "debug",
  "msg": "manager: request queue item",
  "os": "",
  "time": "2020-08-08T19:16:27Z",
  "type": "kubernetes",
  "variant": ""
}
{
  "arch": "",
  "kernel": "",
  "kind": "pipeline",
  "level": "debug",
  "msg": "manager: context canceled",
  "os": "",
  "time": "2020-08-08T19:16:57Z",
  "type": "kubernetes",
  "variant": ""
}
{
  "arch": "",
  "kernel": "",
  "kind": "pipeline",
  "level": "debug",
  "msg": "manager: request queue item",
  "os": "",
  "time": "2020-08-08T19:17:07Z",
  "type": "kubernetes",
  "variant": ""
}
{
  "arch": "",
  "kernel": "",
  "kind": "pipeline",
  "level": "debug",
  "msg": "manager: context canceled",
  "os": "",
  "time": "2020-08-08T19:17:37Z",
  "type": "kubernetes",
  "variant": ""
}
{
  "arch": "",
  "kernel": "",
  "kind": "pipeline",
  "level": "debug",
  "msg": "manager: request queue item",
  "os": "",
  "time": "2020-08-08T19:17:47Z",
  "type": "kubernetes",
  "variant": ""
}
{
  "arch": "",
  "kernel": "",
  "kind": "pipeline",
  "level": "debug",
  "msg": "manager: context canceled",
  "os": "",
  "time": "2020-08-08T19:18:17Z",
  "type": "kubernetes",
  "variant": ""
}
{
  "arch": "",
  "kernel": "",
  "kind": "pipeline",
  "level": "debug",
  "msg": "manager: request queue item",
  "os": "",
  "time": "2020-08-08T19:18:27Z",
  "type": "kubernetes",
  "variant": ""
}
{
  "arch": "",
  "kernel": "",
  "kind": "pipeline",
  "level": "debug",
  "msg": "manager: context canceled",
  "os": "",
  "time": "2020-08-08T19:18:57Z",
  "type": "kubernetes",
  "variant": ""
}
{
  "arch": "",
  "kernel": "",
  "kind": "pipeline",
  "level": "debug",
  "msg": "manager: request queue item",
  "os": "",
  "time": "2020-08-08T19:19:07Z",
  "type": "kubernetes",
```

my **drone runner** log

```
time="2020-08-08T19:13:07Z" level=info msg="starting the server" addr=":3000"
time="2020-08-08T19:13:07Z" level=info msg="successfully pinged the remote server"
time="2020-08-08T19:13:07Z" level=info msg="polling the remote server" capacity=2 endpoint="http://192.168.1.150:30001" kind=pipeline type=kubernetes
```

Not sure how to deal with it as this is my first time facing such issue.I also tried updating the **drone server** image from `1` to `1.9` still nothing happens

Answer (score -1):

I replaced the `'drone/drone-runner-kube:latest'` to `'drone/drone-runner-docker:1'` and specify the mounting point `/var/run/docker.sock`

Comment: and it fixed the issue